# How to keep the FAB toolbar open after clicking a button inside it?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-material

I am using angular material for my ionic app. I came across the fab tool bar and I have included it in my app.
Here is a demo provided in the angular material guide.
[FAB toolbar demo.](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.4/demo/fabToolbar)

This is my code:

```
<md-fab-toolbar md-open=true md-direction='left'>
<md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
  <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
  </md-button>
</md-fab-trigger>
<md-toolbar>
  <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-button aria-label="comment" class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_comment_24px.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <md-button aria-label="label" class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_label_24px.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <md-button aria-label="photo" class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_photo_24px.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </md-fab-actions>
</md-toolbar>
```

The fab tool bar keeps getting closed whenever we press any button inside its content. Is there any way to keep the FAB toolbar open even after clicking a button inside it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an open issue:

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4973

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. But is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by lj-wizard, there is an open issue on github.

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5124

You can try using md-fab-speed-dial as the issue does not occur.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdFabSpeedDial

If you do not set the animation, the buttons will be permanently visible.